# cannot access memory at address 0x10084 when trying to set breakpoint via gdb

Tags: debugging, assembly, memory, arm, gdb

I wrote this simple assembly-program (based on a tutorial, only slightly changed.)

```
@ p = q + r + s
@ let q=2, r=4, s=5
@ this version of the simple-equation stores in memory

p:      .space  4       @reserve 4 bytes in memory for variable p
q:      .word   2       @create 32-bit variable q with initial value of 2
r:      .word   4   
s:      .word   5

        .global _start

_start:

        ldr     r1,q    @load r1 with q
        ldr     r2,r    @load r2 with r
        ldr     r3,s    @load r3 with s

        add     r0,r1,r2
        add     r0,r0,r3

        mov     r7,#1   @syscall to terminate the program
        svc     0

        .end
```

I assemble the program using **as -g -o main.o main.s**
Then i link the object-file usind **ld main.o -o main**
Then i execute **gdb main**
Now, when trying to insert a breakpoint at any line-number, i get the error that is the title of this post (cannot access memory at address  **0x10084**).
As this program's code is based off of a tutorial, and the teacher in the tutorial uses a codeblocks-project and

```
    .global main
main:
```

instead of

```
    .global _start
_start:
```

i assume that this is where my error might come from (although not understanding how this results in not being able to set a breakpoint via gdb, while not getting any error while assembling and linking).
I would be very greatful if anyone could shed some light on this for me.
Thanks in advance!
edit:
having been asked what the output of **objdump -d main** might look like, i add the output of the command here:

```
main:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00010054 <p>:
   10054:       00000000        .word   0x00000000

00010058 <q>:
   10058:       00000002        .word   0x00000002

0001005c <r>:
   1005c:       00000004        .word   0x00000004

00010060 <s>:
   10060:       00000005        .word   0x00000005

00010064 <_start>:
   10064:       e51f1014        ldr     r1, [pc, #-20]  ; 10058 <q>
   10068:       e51f2014        ldr     r2, [pc, #-20]  ; 1005c <r>
   1006c:       e51f3014        ldr     r3, [pc, #-20]  ; 10060 <s>
   10070:       e0810002        add     r0, r1, r2
   10074:       e0800003        add     r0, r0, r3
   10078:       e3a07001        mov     r7, #1
   1007c:       ef000000        svc     0x00000000
```

**readelf -a main** told me (among other things), that my entry point is **0x10064**.

I already tried to use **main** instead of **_start**, however then during disassembling and linking i get an error telling me that no entry point has been found.

edit: 
Given the address of the entry-point, i ran the program again using gdb, then set a breakpoint to the specified address. It did so without complaining, and when running, execution indeed stops at the breakpoint. So the issue seems to be that the address **0x10084** that gdb wants to use for my **breakpoint linenum** command just doesn't correspond to the addresses that the instructions at the corresponding lines really have.

Using the gdb command **info line 'linenumber'** just confirms my 
assumption. It prints out memory addresses and i can indeed set breakpoints to the printed addresses, but when i try to set a breakpoint specifying the line-number, gdb always wants to use **0x10084** and fails.

Does anybody have an idea, how this behaviour comes about, and what might be ways to fix it?

Comment: gdb sometimes prints such messages (e.g. when trying backtraces without frame pointers), are you sure it did not set the breakpoint even so?

Comment: are/were you told to link that way? if you disassemble (objdump -D main) what do you see?   readelf also may help and tell you what your entry point is.  I would try using main not _start and repeat everything to see if the bootstrap has/had a _start...

Comment: @Jester thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it doesn't set the breakpoints in this case. When running the program, it just exits with code 013.

Comment: @old_timer , i appreciate your help. I edited my post to include information relevant to your comment.